# Showing a number with preceding '+' sign

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and Haskell, and having really difficult time understanding making of your own data types. As a learning source I have been using http://learnyouahaskell.com/, but I'm still unable to grasp some ideas.

My specific problem is, that I'm trying to create a show Instance for my custom data type, which always shows '+' symbol in front of whatever is showed (in my case input 555 would be "+555"). This is how I've been trying to solve it.

```
data CountryCode = CountryCode Integer deriving Eq

instance Show CountryCode where
    show _ = "+" : _
```

And this is what I get when I try to load it.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( phonetest.hs, interpreted )

phonetest.hs:6:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    • In the expression: "+" : _
      In an equation for ‘show’: show _ = "+" : _
      In the instance declaration for ‘Show CountryCode’

phonetest.hs:6:20: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: [[Char]]
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: "+" : _
      In an equation for ‘show’: show _ = "+" : _
    • Relevant bindings include
        show :: CountryCode -> String (bound at phonetest.hs:6:5)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I can get something out of the error message, but not enough to make it work correctly. I also tried `show (CountryCode _) = "+" : _` but haskell still complains. To me it seems pretty logical, but clearly there's some basic haskell knowledge I'm lacking.

Comment: So, first hint : `_` isn't actually a variable name. It means "I know something goes here, but please don't give it a name" in patterns (left side of = in this case).and "I know something goes here, but I'm not sure what yet, please tell me its type haskell compiler" in expressions.

Comment: So you need to give a name to things you're going to refer to, those start with lower case letters

Comment: @Cubic I don't understand fully where I'm supposed to give those names. http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#Typeclasses%20102 , section Typeclasses 102 has an example (TrafficLight one) which I tried to follow, and I can't see how it differs from mine, other than mine takes an Integer as a parameter.

Comment: @jiipeezz See http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions: `doubleMe x = x + x` (using a parameter named `x`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unpack the data constructor, and thus obtain the parameter `x`. We can then use guards to check if the value is positive or negative. In case it is positive, we can prepend `'x'` to the result of `show x`:

```
instance Show CountryCode where
    show (CountryCode x) | x >= 0 = '+' : show x
                         | otherwise = show x
```

or we can omit branching in a positive and negative case like [@chepner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022292/showing-a-number-with-preceding-sign/58023362?noredirect=1#comment102460736_58023362) with:

```
instance Show CountryCode where
    show (CountryCode x) = '+' : show x
```

Comment: I think the idea here is to format a telephone country access code, in which case `x`  should be unsigned and the `+` should be used unconditionally, not to indicate a positive value.